# xml error: cannot find the declaration of element "reserva"

Tags: xml

hi guys im trying to make a xml from a xsd file but i get a error saying cannot find the declaration of element xml

[image]

[image]

i cant figure it out can someone help me?

Comment: Post code, not pictures of code

Answer (score 2):

You have defined an `xs:complexType` with the name "Reserva", but you have not defined an element with that name. You can define an element named "Reserva" of type "Reserva":

```
<xs:element name="Reserva" type="Reserva"/>
```

Comment: ty for the reply i have add that line to my xsd and i still have the error i did:

<xs:element name="Reserva" type"="Reserva"/>

<complexType Name ="Reserva">
...
</xs:complexType>

Comment: @sergio95: If you post text, not images, to your question, you'd make it easier for us to provide complete, verified answers that would not require this additional round of follow-up for further clarifications.  Mads' answer is correct.  I suggest that you update your question with a complete [mcve] ***as text, not images***, if you require follow-up help.

Comment: Element names are case-sensitive in XML (unlike HTML and other SGML vocabularies with generic namespacing rules), so try with declaring "reserva" as element name.